# Runtime metadata results: 'warning': 'Optimization level clipped from 3 to 1'

Tags: qiskit

So I ran a Sampler Runtime job and when looking through the job.result() metadata, I got the warning in the metadata part of the job(mentioned in the title) . Is there a reason for this thing? My job id is: cqag4sv0s53g008pnyng.

note: I have already transpiled(using transpile) with optimization_level=3 while specifying the same backend before entering the job to the Sampler... where it also had an optimization_level=3 specified in the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was decided that transpilation at the server side can be only of levels 0 and 1, with default value 1. Since you already transpiled locally with optimization level 3, there is no reason to re-transpile, so you can set it to 0 when you send to the sampler.

Comment: Thank you! I thought so(regarding not needing additional another optimitzation_level=3), but I just wanted to make sure of that.